# Django Class Views and Reverse Urls

Tags: python, django, django-views, reverse

I have a good many class based views that use reverse(name, args) to find urls and pass this to templates. However, the problem is class based views must be instantiated before urlpatterns can be defined. This means the class is instantiated while urlpatterns is empty leading to reverse throwing errors. I've been working around this by passing lambda: reverse(name, args) to my templates but surely there is a better solution.

As a simple example the following fails with exception:
ImproperlyConfigured at xxxx
The included urlconf mysite.urls doesn't have any patterns in it

mysite.urls

```
from mysite.views import MyClassView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$' MyClassView.as_view(), name='home')
)
```

views.py

```
class MyClassView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        home_url = reverse('home')
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'home_url':home_url})
```

home.html

```
<p><a href={{ home_url }}>Home</a></p>
```

I'm currently working around the problem by forcing reverse to run on template rendering by changing views.py to

```
class MyClassView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        home_url = lambda: reverse('home')
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'home_url':home_url})
```

and it works, but this is really ugly and surely there is a better way. So is there a way to use reverse in class based views but avoid the cyclic dependency of urlpatterns requiring view requiring reverse requiring urlpatterns...

EDIT:

I'm using this as so:

views.py

```
def sidebar_activeusers(cls):
    sidebar_dict = {'items' = []}
    qs = models.random.filter.on.users
    for user in qs:
        item = {
            'value': user.name,
            'href': reverse('user_profile', args=[hash_id(user.id)])}
    sidebar = loader.get_template('sidebar.html')
    cls.base_dict['sidebar_html'] = sidebar.render(Context(sidebar_dict))
    return cls

@sidebar_activeusers
class MyView1(View):
    base_dict = {}
    ...

@other_sidebar_that_uses_same_sidebar_template
class MyView2(View):
```

basically I'd like to use the same sidebar template for a few different content types. Although the models displayed in the sidebar will be arbitrary the format will always be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example `MyClassView`, it's ok to use `reverse`

```
class MyClassView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        home_url = reverse_lazy('home')
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'home_url': home_url},
```

The `reverse` method is not called when the class is defined -- It is only called when the request is processed and the `get` method is called, so there shouldn't be an error. I have tested the example above and it works fine.

However, When you use your `sidebar_activeusers` decorator, the `reverse` call occurs before the url conf is loaded. In cases like these, you can use [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy). Here's an example of `reverse_lazy` in action:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class MyOtherClassView(View):
    home_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'home_url':self.home_url})
```

This time, `home_url` is set when the class is defined, so `reverse_lazy` is required instead of reverse, because the url conf hasn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your `home` url can be accessed directly in your template by using declaring `{% url 'home' %}`. It's a standard way to access your named urls in your urls.py file.

You do not have to send the `home_url` variable to your template explicitly in your class-based view function.

In other words, in your `home.html` file:-

```
<p><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></p>
```

will do.

Comment: The above was just a simple example to demonstrate the usage. I'll update my post with a better example to show why I can't use this.